# Does pryr::object_size() play poorly with nesting in tibbles and/or data frames?

Tags: r, dataframe, tibble, pryr

When trying to run `pryr::object_size()` on a nested tibble or data frame, I receive the error below:

```
Error in obj_size_(dots, env, size_node(), size_vector()) :
   bad binding access
```

Is this caused by having nesting in the data frames and/or tibbles? I cannot paste here exactly what I am working on, but here is a reproducible example:

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)
library(pryr)

DT = data.table(x=c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100), y=c(10,30,66,75,81,101,135,143,181,210))
dt= data.frame(x=c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100), y=c(10,30,66,75,81,101,135,143,181,210))

testTabe <- function(dat){
   tib <- data.table(
      type = 'rate',
      data = list(dat %>% mutate(
            logX = log(x),
            logY = log(y)
            )
   )
 )%>% mutate(
  model = tryCatch(lm(logY ~ logX, data=data[[1]]), error=function(cond) NA) %>% list()
 )
 return(tib)
}

testTib <- function(dat){
   tib <- tibble(
      type = 'rate',
      data = list(dat %>% mutate( 
            logX = log(x),
            logY = log(y)
            )
   )
 )%>% mutate(
  model = tryCatch(lm(logY ~ logX, data=data[[1]]), error=function(cond) NA) %>% list()
 )
 return(tib)
}

object_size(testTabe(DT))

object_size(testTib(DT))
```

From the above example specifically, I get the error on both `object_size()` calls. Is this because they are nested? Is it something else? I've tried `object_size()` on every unnested thing I could think of and it always works. Is there a workaround for this?